# How to save excel of particular sheets into another excel sheet python

Tags: python, excel

I have an excel

- There are 25 sheet in the excel
- I need to extract sheet starting with TXN into another separate `individual`excel sheets

I am doing with below code which is not proper way

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('TXN-data.xlsx', sheet_name='TXN-20210101')
df1 = pd.read_excel('TXN-data.xlsx',sheet_name='TXN-20210102')
```

After that i am saving

```
df.to_excel('TXN-20210101.xlsx')
df1.to_excel('TXN-20210102.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.ExcelFile('TXN-data.xlsx')
sheets = df.sheet_names
sheets_selected = [x for x in sheets if x[0:3]=="TXN"]

for sheet in sheets_selected:
    df_sheet = pd.read_excel(df, sheet)
    df_sheet.to_excel(sheet + ".xlsx")
```

Comment: Not saving.. ValueError: No engine for filetype: ''

Comment: saving  i changed to df_sheet.to_excel(sheet+".xlsx")